# Dividing polynomial $f(x)$ by $x-3$ and $x+6$ leaves respective remainders $7$ and $22$. What's the remainder upon dividing by $(x-3)(x+6)$?

Tags: polynomials

If I have a polynomial $f(x)$ and is divided by $(x- 3)$ and $(x + 6)$ the respective remainders are $7$ and $22$, what is the remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by $(x-3)(x + 6)$?

I tried it by doing:

$$f(x) =(x-3)(x+6)q(x) + ax+b $$
And, $a$ and $b$ comes out to be $-\dfrac53$ and $12$ respectively.

But I'm not sure how to solve any further.
And kindly explain exactly how it's done

Comment: Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: You got that the remainder is $-\frac53x+12$. What else do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$f(x)=Q1(x-3)+7$$ and $$f(x)=Q2(x+6)+22$$ (**where Q1 and Q2 are some** **functions of x, since degree of f can be 2)**

So, if you substitute **x=3** and **x=-6** in above equations respectively, you get **f(3)=7** and **f(-6)=22**

Now, let $$f(x)=Q3(x-3)(x+6)+(ax+b)$$ **where (ax+b) is remainder**
(remainder may be a **constant** or a **linear in x** because of degree restriction over f(x))

Substitute **x=3** $$f(3)=0+(3a+b)  $$
Substitute **x=-6** $$f(-6)=0+(-6a+b)$$
So, **3a+b=7** and **-6a+b=22**

Solving, $$a= \frac{-5}{3}$$ and $$b=12  $$
Remainder is $$ \frac{-5x}{3}+12$$

Comment: In fact we can avoid solving equations - see my answer

Answer (score 2):

A [slick way](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2021696/242) via $\ {ab\bmod ac = a(b\bmod c)} = $ [mod Distributive Law,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242) $ $ is to add $\ f(3) = 7\ $ to

$\quad f(x)\!-\!f(3)\bmod  (x\!-\!3)(x\!+\!6)\, =\, (x\!-\!3)\Bigg[\dfrac{\overbrace{f(x)\!-\!f(3)}^{\Large\color{#c00}{ 22\ \ -\ \ 7}\ }}{\underbrace{x - 3}_{\large\color{#c00}{\Large  -6\ -\ 3\ }\ \ }}\underbrace{\bmod_{\phantom{1_{1_1{1_{1_{1_1}}}}}}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! x\!+\!6}_{\Large\Rightarrow\ \ x\ \equiv\  \color{#c00}{-6}\!}\Bigg]  =\, \color{#c00}{-\dfrac{5}3}(x\!-\!3)  $

Comment: seems better, but a bit above my understanding...not so familiar with modular algebra...

Comment: @omega The f[irst linked post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2021696/242) shows how to do it without mod.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=(x-3)a(x)+7\Rightarrow f(3)=7$

### $f(x)=(x+6)b(x)+22\Rightarrow f(-6)=22$

If you can write $f$ is of the form $f(x) =(x-3)(x+6)q(x) + ax+b$.

Solution is so easy:

$$f(3)=3a+b=7$$
$$f(-6)=-6a+b=22$$

Hence,  $a=-\dfrac53$ and $b=12$