# $f$ dividing by $x + 1$ have remainder 4, when dividing with $x^2 + 1$ have remainder 2x+3. Find remainder dividing polynomial with($x+1$)($x^2+1$)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Problem: The polynomial $f$ dividing by ($x + 1$) gives the remainder 4, and when dividing with ($x^2 + 1$) gives the remainder (2x+3). Determine the remainder when dividing the polynomial with ($x + 1$)($x^2 + 1$)?

My attempt:
By Polynomial remainder theorem we know that 
$$f(x)=q_1(x)(x+1)+4$$
$$f(x)=q_2(x)(x^2+1)+(2x+3)$$
By putting $x=1$ we know that $f(-1)=4, f(i)=2i+3, f(-i)=-2i+3$
We want to find $r(x)$ such that: $$f(x)=(x+1)(x^2+1)q_3(x) + r(x) .$$
By applying the previous idea we know that $f(-1)=r(-1)=4$, but the same idea $r(i)=2i+3$ and $r(-i)=-2i+3$ but this is only three point and we need to determinant polynomial $r(x)$ of degree 3...
Please solve without modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

The hint.

Since $\deg((x+1)(x^2+1))=3,$ the degree of $r$ must be less than $3$.

Let $r(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and take $x=-1$, $x=i$ and $x=-i$.

Now, solve the following system.
$$a-b+c=4,$$
$$-a+bi+c=2i+3$$ and
$$-a-bi+c=-2i+3.$$
I got $$r(x)=1.5x^2+2x+4.5.$$

Comment: You didn't show how "you got" the solutions for $\,a,b,c\ \ $

Answer (score 2):

Upon applying the law:  $\,ab\bmod ac = a(b\bmod c) = $ [Mod Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242) we obtain

$(f\!-\!(2x\!+\!3))\bmod{(x^2\!+\!1)(x\!+\!1)}\,=\, (x^2\!+\!1){\Huge[}\dfrac{\overbrace{f\!-\!(2x\!+\!3)}^{\large 4\,-\,(2(\color{#c00}{\bf -1})+3)}}{\underbrace{x^2\!+\!1}_{\large (\color{#c00}{\bf -1})^2+1\ \ \ \ }}\underbrace{\bmod{x\!+\!1}}_{\Large x\ \equiv\ \color{#c00}{\bf {-}1}}{\Huge]}=\, (x^2\!+\!1)\left[\dfrac{3}{2}\right]$

So $\, f\equiv  2x\!+\!3 + \dfrac{3}2(x^2\!+\!1).\ $  Note that we did not need to solve any equations - just evaluate.

Comment: [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2021696/242) for further examples and  discussion of the close relationship with CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem and Lagrange interpolation.